# naming a row after using rollup

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Having used 'roll up' I'm having an issue with 2 rows being called 'Total'.  The bottom 'Total' should be called 'N/A'

```
  Name        Col1     Col2
  Total        10       12
    A           5        2
    B           4        4
    C           0        4    
  Total         1        2
```

Should look like this

```
   Name        Col1     Col2
   Total        10       12
    A           5        2
    B           4        4
    C           0        4    
    N/A         1        2
```

This Is part of my query where I'm doing something wrong

```
   select

   case Name when 'N/A' then 'Total' else Name end as Name     
   ,col1
   ,col2

   from 

   (  

    case NameID when '1' then 'A'
                when '2' then 'B'
                when '3' then 'C'
                else 'N/A'
    end as Name
    ,col1  --these are sums
    ,col2  --these are sums

     from table
     group by NameID with rollup 

     )a
```

If I make a change to this bit

```
   case NameID when '1' then 'A'
                when '2' then 'B'
                when '3' then 'C'
                else 'help'
    end as Name
```

The outcome is this

```
       Name        Col1     Col2
       help        10       12
       A           5        2
       B           4        4
       C           0        4    
       help        1        2
```

All help much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Your example has no `rollup` so it is hard to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

One of your `NAMEs` is Total it seems, so why not swap them. Seems to be what you want.

```
case 
  when NAME =  'N/A' then 'Total' 
  when NAME = 'Total' then 'N/A'
  else Name 
end as Name
```